# ng-repeat not updating the view

Tags: angularjs

I have this function inside my controller and I am using ng-repeat to update the view. 
The thing is the view is not getting updated even if I use $scope.$apply() in the controller below. I am probably missing something here.

I have verified by debugging that

```
   $scope.files = promise.file;
```

is getting the values correctly, yet ng-repeat associated to $scope.files is not getting updated.

Controller:

```
  $scope.prevDirFiles = function(){
    var currDir = fileSvc.getCurrDir();
    var arr = currDir.split('/');
    var rebuildDir = config.rootDirectory;
    for(var i=1; i<arr.length-1;i++){
        rebuildDir += '/'+arr[i]
    }
    // Load File based on rebuilt directory path
    fileSvc.setPath(rebuildDir);

    $scope.$apply(fileSvc.getfiles().then(
        function(promise){
            $scope.files = promise.file;
        }
    ));
}
```

Service:

```
 this.getfiles = function(){
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var url = config.url + 'api_all';
    console.log("Path is: ");
    console.log(this.path);
    $http({method:'POST', url:url,data: {path:this.path}})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deffered.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deffered.reject({"status": false});
        });
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

Can someone please guide me as to where I am wrong.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<ul class="list" ng-repeat="file in files">
    <li class="list-main" ng-click="getFiles('{{file['file-path']}}','{{file['file-name']}}')" >
        <img src="images/cloud.png" class="img">
        <div class="list-info">
            <div class="list-header">{{file['file-name']}}</div>
            <!--<div class="list-info-bottom">Last Modified on 01-Aug-2013 15:38:38</div>-->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller Function bound to ng-click

```
$scope.getFiles = function(fpath,fname){
    var path = fpath +'/'+fname;
    fileSvc.setCurrDir(path);
    console.log(path);
    fileSvc.setPath(path);

    fileSvc.getfiles().then(
        function(promise){
            $scope.files = promise.file;
        }
    )

}
```

Even after applying $apply on $scope.files, the 2nd function prevDirFiles is not updating the view.

```
$scope.prevDirFiles = function(){
    fileSvc.getCurrentWorkingDirectory().then(
        function(response){
            var arr = response.split('/');
            var rebuildDir = config.rootDirectory;
            for(var i=1; i<arr.length-1;i++){
                rebuildDir += '/'+arr[i]
            }
            fileSvc.setPath(rebuildDir);
            fileSvc.getfiles().then(
                function(response){
                    $scope.$apply($scope.files = response.file);
                }
            );
        })

}
```

Comment: Please share the html for the ng-repeat

Comment: Updated with HTML code.

Comment: `Response` or `data` is a better name for what you are calling promise. `fileSvc.getfiles()` returns an XHR promise object, your use of variablename promise is misleading.

Comment: If the function getFiles is in your service, then the ng-click is looking for a function on your $scope in the controller, can it access this?

Comment: What is this 'ng-click="getFiles('{{file['file-path']}}'' supposed to do? After clicking inside your button, have you checked via a debugger that it goes into the function you want to?
I'm not sure a service can be called that way from the vue. And the camelcase is not respected everywhere

Comment: Yes that function is there and it works fine. I will update the post with it.

Comment: That functions works, I mean when it gets fired the data in $scope.files gets updated and is also updated in the view, so the thing is why isn't the other function doing the same, when the code is almost the same

Comment: Note that you don't need curly braces in `getFiles('{{file['file-path']}}','{{file['file-name']}}')`

Comment: Removing curly braces getFiles('file['file-path']','file['file-name']') doesn't seem to work. The values are not getting updated from the ng-repeat.

Comment: Hmmm single quotes mess it up!

Comment: Just noticed that you are not doing $apply in the `getFiles()` method. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: 1 - doesnt the $apply should be on $scope.files?    2 - try using broadcast instead

Comment: I tried by applying $apply on $scope.files, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @bresleveloper Can you please point me to some reference on using $broadcast. I am total noob!

Comment: As your answer suggests, this question + answer doesn't make any sense. You can delete it if you think you should free up some space at the SO :) .

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found out why this was not working. I had another  ...  in index.html outside app-body. It actually was the button which was triggering prevDirFiles() function as  had ng-controller="FilesCtrl" . And also in the route, I had defined for the page had controller as before FilesCtrl. I am not sure exactly how and what went wrong inside in angularjs (if someone knows please do explain), it got fixed when i removed the controller from header.